# Shell Script to find disk usage of the directory

Tags: shell, unix

I need to find the disk usage of a specific directory. I don't want the listing for files.

I have used

```
find /home/a491504/ -type d -exec du -akS {} \;
```

Is there any other way to fetch the directory list with disk usage? (% disk usage would be great)

Comment: man du will show you -s option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `du -s`

example:

```
~ $ du -sh /home/shaman/tmp/
12M /home/shaman/tmp/
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `du -sh`

From man page:

```
-s, --summarize       display only a total for each argument
-h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation and congratulations for completing 50K :)